# Find the number of digits in $2^{2^{22}}$ without logarithms.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I just wanted to know if there is a way to find the number of digits in $2^{2^{22}}$ with plain number theory techniques. Can't figure out how to do it on my own. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What motivates you to search for a method without log... By the way, all answers to the same question asked before use logarithms, the easy way...

Comment: Well there is one way: calculate the exact answer and count the number of digits. This will ensure that you do it without logarithm. Of course my method might take some months (read years) but it will be enough to evoke an interest in using logarithm **Note:** Don't try this at home, school, college, university or anywhere.

Comment: Through inequalities?

Comment: You can get a quick estimate with the approximation $2^{10} \approx 10^3$.

Comment: In gp: (14:22) gp > length(Str(2^(2^22)))
%8 = 1262612

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that $2^{10}$ is about $1000$ and $2^{20}$ is about $1,000,000$.  So $2^{22}$ is about $4$ million.  Then

$$2^{2^{22}} \approx  2^{4000000} = (2^{10})^{400000} \approx (10^3)^{400000}=10^{1200000}.$$

So we expect about $1.2$ million digits.  By log's we get about $1.26$ million.