# bounding to get Number of digits without logs

Tags: number-theory

I would like to prove that $10^{168} \le 2^{561}< 10^{169}$ (to get the number of digits of the power of two, if possible without the use of logarithms.

The idea came to me from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593015/find-the-number-of-digits-in-2222-without-logarithms?answertab=active#tab-top)

Using the fact that $5^3<2^7$ gives $10^{168}<2^{560}$.

Any advice to improve this bound and get the other are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Using log it is between $10^{168}$ and $10^{169}$ though.

Comment: using wolfram $\floor{log(2^{561})} +1= 169$

Comment: Which means that $10^{169}$ is the upper bound.

Comment: fixed thanks, the RHS inequality is apparently the trickier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the inequality $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{nx} < e^n$ when $x > 0$, you get

$$
\begin{aligned}
2^{561} &= 2\cdot (2^{10})^{56} = 2\cdot10^{168}\cdot (1+0.024)^{56}\\
&< 2\cdot 10^{168} \cdot e^{1.344}\\
&< 2\cdot 10^{168} \cdot 2.89^{1.5} = 2\cdot 10^{168}\cdot 1.7^3\\
&= 2\cdot 4.913 \cdot 10^{168} < 10^{169}.
\end{aligned}
$$